# Angular - Bootstrap modal showing but not as dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

Working on my first Angular project I am trying to implement a dialog asking for a confirmation before deleting an item. I am using ng-bootstrap and the examples in the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) as a starting point.

The problem I am having: I can open and close the modal as expected, but the modal is not showing as a dialog window. It opens as a "normal" div below the rest of the content.

I have created a "ConfirmComponent" component which I am trying to use in another component.

**confirm.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirm',
  templateUrl: './confirm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm.component.scss']
})
export class ConfirmComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**confirm.component.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
</div>
```

This is the html of the component where I try to open the dialog

**game-list.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Available Games</h1>

    <ul *ngIf="games">
        <li *ngFor="let game of games">
            <a href="#" routerLink="/games/{{ game.pk }}" class="btn btn-secondary">{{ game.pk }}</a>
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-danger text-danger" (click)="open()"><mat-icon>delete_outlined</mat-icon></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="createGame()">New Game</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding component

**game-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { Game } from '../game';
import { GameServiceService } from '../game-service.service';
import { ConfirmComponent } from '../confirm/confirm.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-list',
  templateUrl: './game-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-list.component.scss']
})
export class GameListComponent implements OnInit {

  games: Game[] = []

  constructor(private gameService: GameServiceService, private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGames();
  }

  getGames(): void {
    this.gameService.getGames().subscribe(games => this.games = games);
  }

  createGame(): void {
    this.gameService.createGame().subscribe(game => this.games.push(game));
  }

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }

}
```

I think the imports in my app.module.ts are correct:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GameListComponent } from './game/game-list/game-list.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GameDetailComponent } from './game/game-detail/game-detail.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { PlayerComponent } from './game/player/player.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { ConfirmComponent } from './game/confirm/confirm.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GameListComponent,
    GameDetailComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    PlayerComponent,
    ConfirmComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DragDropModule,
    NgbModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My suspicion (which might be wrong) is that some vital style document is missing. In my Firefox Browser console I am getting a warning `Style document could no be loaded: http://myurl/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_type.scss` - don't know whether this relevant as I could not spot any dialog relevant styles in the source of that document.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the issue.

Comment: you need download a bootstrap.min.css (only the .css) in a folder and add in angular.json -in the "tag" styles -before `"src/styles.css"`

Comment: @Eliseo: Thanks for your quick reply. bootstrap.min.css is in my 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist' folder already. Never having edited angular.json manually: I do have multiple tags called "style" but no tag called "css". Not quite sure where to add the bootstrap css. I guess in the "style" tag of the "build" options as well as the style tag of the "serve" options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Eliseo comment I found the solution. After adding the following line to the global `style.scss` file it worked as expected:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Additional information can be found [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

Comment: Cris, you can add in style.scc or edit your angular.json (the two options are valid). the "tag" you need change in angular.json is in projects-->ClientApp-->architect-->build-->options-->styles, you has some like `["src/styles.cscc"]`, you can add, so styles becomes like `["bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss","src/styles.cscc"]` (*)really I don't know where you has your "bootstrap.scss", think that you need put the path as you part from the folder of your project

Comment: @Eliseo, thanks for your additional explanation. For some reason the angular.json approach did not work for me, maybe I got the path wrong. Anyway, you put me on the right track and thanks to your help I was able to solve the issue in short time after struggling for hours before.